# Adding wamp server to aptana

Tags: php, aptana, wamp, wampserver, aptana3

Am trying to setup wamp server in aptana 3. So while editing external web server configuration, there are 2 more options, start command and stop command of wamp server. can anybody tell me what I need to specify there??

Answer (score 2):

Try this for the start command:

```
NET START wampapache
```

and this for the stop command:

```
NET STOP wampapache
```